# R - Making ggplot look good for 2-color printing?

Tags: r, graphics, plot, colors, ggplot2

I make lots of graphs for publication in scientific journals, so I tend to use the basic `plot` toolset in R, which produces simple graphics that look professional in 2-color format.  But sometimes I want some fancier functionality, such as is provided by `ggplot`.

How can I generate `ggplot` graphs with the "look and feel" of R's base graphing functionality, or that otherwise will print cleanly in two color format?

Comment: Take a look at `theme_bw` and see if it helps.

Comment: And if you are mapping anything to `colour`/`fill`, you can use `scale_colour_grey`/`scale_fill_grey`.

Comment: You can find examples easily, E.g., this: http://www.noamross.net/blog/2013/11/20/formatting-plots-for-pubs.html

Answer (score 0):

For full control you can create a 'theme' function to apply to your plots, based on the wide range of graphical parameters `ggplot2` caters for.

The function below is not exhaustive, but it makes lots of subtle changes to the base ggplot theme. All of the parameters can be easily amended. For example, change the font family (here 'Helvetica'). Or move the title up and down using the `vjust` parameter of the `plot.title`.

```
myTheme <- function() {
theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour ='white'),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'white'),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = '#ededed', color = '#ededed'),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', color = 'white'),
    plot.margin = unit(c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5), 'cm'),
    plot.title = element_text(family = 'Helvetica', face ='bold', vjust=4, size=12, colour='#292929'),
    axis.title.y = element_text(family = 'Helvetica', size = 12, vjust = 1.5, face='bold', colour='#292929'),
    axis.title.x = element_text(family = 'Helvetica', size = 12, vjust = -1.5, face='bold',colour='#292929'),
    axis.text.y = element_text(family = 'Helvetica', size = 11, colour = '#292929'),
    axis.text.x = element_text(family='Helvetica', size = 11, colour='#292929'),
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = 'white'),
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = 'white'))
}
```

I personally prefer to have more space at the margins of the plot. For this, you need:

```
install.packages('grid')
library(grid)
```

This package enables you to adjust the `plot.margin` parameter.

Using this function is very simple. You just add it to the end of your ggplot code. As follows.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
geom_point() +
ggtitle('Mtcars Plot') +
myTheme()
```

And as rightly mentioned in the comments above, adding the options `scale_fill_grey()` or `scale_colour_grey()` to your ggplot code as appropriate enable you to control the shades of grey.

With the theme as it is, your plots will be minimal like the one below and more in keeping with the base plots. To understand how to control the elements of the theme in more detail, see here: [ggplot 2 theme control](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html)

[image: Minimal Mtcars Plot]